# В чём разница между статической и динамической линковкой?

Tags: c++, c, компиляция

В чём разница между статической и динамической линковкой?

Почему когда гуглятся эти словосочетания выдаётся результат про статические и динамические библиотеки? Это что одно и то же или происходят те же действия?

А как это тогда связано с линковкой объектного файла: например я написал код, он прошёл этапы препроцессора, компиляции и появления объектного файла, а дальше линковка. И как тогда понять, как линкуется в VS объектный файл в .exe : динамически или статически? 
Но всё же главный вопрос: в чём разница между статической и динамической линковкой?

Comment: Статическая библиотека - это лишь архив объектных файлов. Поэтому никакой фундаментальной разницы между линковкой статической библиотеки и линковкой объектного файла нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам все выводилось правильно.
Линковка (ну или компоновка) последний этап сборки. Все что происходит на этом этапе подчиняется linker скрипту.

Ближе к телу:

Когда Вы собираете Ваш проект, и хотите включить в него библиотеку(собранную Статически или Динамически *.a или *.so) происходит связывание ld всего Вашего кода. Когда вы где-то пишите, что тут будет вызываться функция библиотеки A, компилятор оставляет там пометку (по сути обещание), что референс на данные call будет подставлен на этапе линковки. Далее ликовщик смотрит на флаги связывания SHARED или STATIC(что и отвечает за динамическую или статическую библиотеку) и ищет ее согласно стандартным путям и/или указанным Вами путям.

Статическая библиотека - (*.a) собрана для непосредственного встраивания в Ваш исполняемый файл. Она просто будет помещена в соответствии с указанием linker'а.
Тут будет статическая линковка.

Динамическая библиотека - (*.so) - будет просто подключаться как link на референс и  не попадет в Ваш бинарь. Будет лишь указание где брать референс на тот или иной функционал.  Тут будет динамическая линковка.